# IIS Web Sites versus Virtual Directories - why one or the other?

Tags: iis

Though I've used both, I never really "got" the decisions or pros/cons that go into whether or not to choose a web site as the root entity of a new app, or a virtual directory underneath an existing web site. I have a vague idea, mostly involving "well, is it a sublocation of a master site that needs its own configuration?," but I'm not sure that's entirely accurate. I have application pools down pat, but never understood this difference.

So, question. **What's the difference between a web site and a virtual directory in IIS, and why would you choose one over the other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference is that you can assign different Web Sites to different URLs. This allows you to use:

app1.mydomain.com
app2.mydomain.com

Instead of:

mydomain.com/app1
mydomain.com/app2

Which is considered by most people "Cleaner".

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic answer

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29944368&threadid=29944365

Resuming with and exemple ...

WEB SITE URL = www.company1.com or portal.company1.com

VIRTUAL DIRECTORY URL = www.yoursite.com/portal1