# Are session values shared between sibling web apps?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have several web apps on the parent website in IIS.
ie the URLs are

```
mysite.com/app1
mysite.com/app2
etc
```

The code base is identical but as far as I am concerned they should be separate and isolated - different app pools, databases, physical folder etc

Somehow they aware of each other.
When I log on to one app it logs me off from the other - this is by design in the software using `HttpContext` and `FormsAuthenticationTicket`, but should only be happening within the same app, not across others.

This does not happen when the apps are fully separated
ie

```
app1.mysite.com
app2.mysite.com
etc
```

What's going on?

I can find very little info on the effects of 'nested apps' other than inheriting from the parent web.config (there isn't one).
The answers to this similar question don't reveal much [IIS Web Sites versus Virtual Directories - why one or the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915816/iis-web-sites-versus-virtual-directories-why-one-or-the-other?rq=1)

Comment: Ensure that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiepath(v=vs.110).aspx) is not set to "/". Needs to be different per app.

Comment: @JohnWu The authentication section in both web.config files is as follows. Can you explain a bit more what's going on?  
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".COOKIENAME" loginUrl="~/WebLogin.aspx" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>

Comment: The browser doesn't know about "web apps" and doesn't see much difference between "mysite.com/app1" and "mysite.com/app2". Both are some URL on host "mysite.com", so both get all cookies for domain "mysite.com". Unless you can narrow down those cookies to some specific path

Comment: @HansKesting Thanks, that makes sense.  So in summary it's a behaviour of the browser on the same client machine not the server.  In other words I shouldn't see this problem if different people on different machines try the same thing, which is ultimately what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed the cookie name to be unique for each site.

Thanks to @HansKestng and @JohnWu